# Настройка роутинга React приложения на WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

Привет!Я настроил роутинг сайта на React.js и без WordPress все работало,но как я закинул на WordPress то он не понимает откуда ему взять файлы.Как мне сделать так чтобы когда я запускаю сайт с WP подгружался сайт с папки sourse?Загружать посты буду через RestAPI.
Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import {
    HashRouter,
    Route,
  } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
    <div>
     <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    </div>
   </HashRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На скриншоте архитектура файлов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где wp-includes, wp-content, wp-admin???

Comment: Они есть,обновил вопрос.

Comment: Что значит, не понимает, отукуда взять файлы? Я бы в корень сайт поместил то, что у вас в source, WP вынес в подпапку, скажем, /wp, и задал настройки .htaccess https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess. React должен отзываться на  PortlandWP.com, а WP - на PortlandWP.com/wp

Comment: Я добавил эту строку в .htacess `Redirect /index.php /public/index.html` но теперь белая страница просто.Добавил скриншот как сменил архитектуру в вопрос.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы сделали. Еще раз. Весь WordPress попробуйте положить в `webserver/OpenServer/domains/PortlandWP.com/wp`, а файлы react.js в `webserver/OpenServer/domains/PortlandWP.com`. Добейтесь того, чтобы React отзывался на url `PortlandWP.com`, а WordPress в браузере был доступен по url `PortlandWP.com/wp`

Comment: Сделал.Но сможет ли теперь react принимать API WordPress на локальном сервере?

Comment: Что значит принимать API? Это всего лишь http запрос. Вам надо чтобы они работали на одном домене, при этом wp в подпапке

Comment: Получается моим доменом будет для API-запросов будет Portland.com/wp

Comment: Ну конечно. Именно так.